# Зачем классу String метод getBytes(), если в Java byte редуцированный?

Tags: java, filewriter, fileoutputstream

Решил проверить, как ведет себя метод `getBytes()` класса `String`, когда code point буквы имеет значение, большее 127. Взял для примера строку с латинскими и кириллическими символами, которую преобразовал в массив байтов:

`byte[] bytes = "abcdefghijz<аБ".getBytes();`

Получил следующие байты:

`[97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 122, 60, -32, -63]`

Как видно, из-за переполнения типа `byte` code point `а=224` и `Б=193` сместился в отрицательную область `-32` и `-63`, соответственно.

Далее преобразую байтовый массив в массив `char`

```
char[] chars=new char[bytes.length];
    for (int i=0;i<bytes.length;i++)
        chars[i]=(char)bytes[i];
```

Получаю

`[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, z, <, ?, ?]`

Как и ожидалось, char для отрицательных значений не определен, и вместо них IDE рисует знаки `?`

Далее проверяю, как Java работает с этими `char` при записи в файл. Первый способ:

```
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("chars.txt");
BufferedOutputStream bos=new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
bos.write(bytes,0,bytes.length);
bos.close();
```

При использовании `FileOutputStream` программа корректно отображает кириллические буквы, вместо знаков вопроса в текстовом файле имеются буквы `а` и `Б`, а при открытии файла в шестнадцатеричном редакторе на месте букв стоят корректные значения байтов `224` и `193`, а не отрицательные числа, которые изначально выдала программа

Второй способ записи в файл:

```
FileWriter fos=new FileWriter("chars.txt");
fos.write(chars,0,chars.length);
fos.close();
```

При использовании `FileWriter` в текстовом файле вместо кириллических символов отображаются вопросительные знаки, а при открытии файла в шестнадцатеричном редакторе знак вопроса отображается как байт `63` (а не `224` и `193`, которые были заложены в строку изначально)

Отсюда возникают следующие вопросы:

1) Я ожидал, что `FileWriter` корректно отобразит кириллические символы, которые в стандартной кодировке windows (`windows-1251`) помещаются в один байт. Почему это не так? Я знаю, что `FileWriter` - это символьный, а не байтовый поток. Но ведь символьные потоки так же оперируют байтами. Если изначально заложен байт символа `а=224`, то разве программа не должна на низком уровне записать в файл этот же байт? При просмотре в текстовом редакторе может отображаться что-то другое, если неправильно кодировка подобрана и байту 224 соответствует какой-то иероглиф. Но почему же `FileWriter` записывает совсем другой байт?

2) Зачем все-таки классу `String` метод `getBytes()`, если в Java он имеет не тот диапазон, который традиционно используется в компьютерной технике? Вроде бы в компьютерной технике никто отрицательными числами не оперирует?

Comment: Восемь бит как тип данных может в разных языках программирования определяться по-разному. Если вы пишете на Java, то обязаны знать что `Java's primitive byte data type is always defined as consisting of 8 bits and being a signed data type, holding values from −128 to 127.`

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить - что означает "редуцированный"?

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець может я неправильно понимаю как в джаве с байтами работать, но они имеют не полный диапазон значений того байта, которым оперируют в computer science. вместо 0 (тире) 255 почему-то используются -128 (тире) 127. Логично, что когда мы вызываем в `String` метод `getBytes` мы хотим получить кодепойнты символов из стандартной кодировки. но при выходе кодепойнта за пределы 127 возвращается нечто другое, с чем непонятно как работать

Comment: Да, а ответ на мой вопрос?

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець редуцированный - значит неполный, уменьшенный. Из-за того, что в джаве байт знаковый, он может принимать положительных значений в два раза меньше

Comment: @Dmitry Это джава, детка (С) )))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
byte[] bytes = "abcdefghijz<аБ".getBytes();
```

это не совсем полная версия, полная версия такая:

```
byte[] bytes = "abcdefghijz<аБ".getBytes(charset); //charset - кодировка строки
```

то есть выдаваемые байты зависят от применяемой кодировки. В первом случае берется кодировка по умолчанию установленная в системе (обычно Win-1251).

Строка `abcdefghijz<аБ` - в какой кодировке записана? Видимо, в UTF-8 - оттуда у вас и разночтения.

По второму вопросу:

> Вроде бы в компьютерной технике никто отрицательными числами не оперирует?

оставлю на вашей совести. Байт он и в Африке байт, а как его отображать положительными или отрицательными числами (в десятичном исчислении) - это уже всего лишь способ отображения.

**Update**

`OutputStream` работает с готовым массивом *raw* байтов, в противоположность ему `OutputStreamWriter` перекодидирует готовый массив байтов в `char` согласно заложенному при его создании `CharSet`. В случае же `FileWriter`, каковой является наследником `OutputStreamWriter`, то согласно документации:

> The constructors of this class assume that the default character encoding and the default byte-buffer size are acceptable. To specify these values yourself, construct an OutputStreamWriter on a FileOutputStream.

P.S. Советую внимательно отнестись к моему замечанию:

> Строка `abcdefghijz<аБ` - в какой кодировке записана?

**Ван мор апдейт**

`char` и `byte` понятие нетождественные. Чтобы было понятно - возьмем чисто русскую букву `Ж` (же большое)

- в Юникоде это `0x04 0x16` (два байта)
- в Win-1251 - `0xC6` (1 байт)
- в KOI-8 - `0xD6` (1 байт)

и т.д.

Теперь представим - есть набор байтов и мы его читаем. Внимание вопрос: как нам понять какие из себя представляют символы в этом наборе байтов? Правильно - без априорного знания кодировки мы узнать не сможем (вернее можем, но скажем так только путем определенных умозаключений/построений - как например [здесь](https://www.artlebedev.ru/decoder/)) - соответственно надо дать на вход чтецу таблицу перекодировки байтов в символы/`Char` - это и называется перекодировка.

Comment: "то есть выдаваемые байты зависят от применяемой кодировки"
байты, которые выдал метод `toString()` меня устраивают. Они же корректно преобразовались в текст при помощи `FileOutputStream`, правильно? Значит проблема кроется в классе `FileWriter`. Он почему-то производит подмену байтов.

Comment: Поясню - мне не важно, какие символы отображаются в файле `*.txt`. Я открываю этот файл шестнадцатеричным редактором и смотрю только на записанные байты. Отображение байта на конкретный символ - это уже шаманство с кодировками, которое сейчас не рассматривается.

Итак, что мы имеем: байты, полученные при помощи метода `toString()`. Класс `FileOutputStream` корректно копирует байты в файл, без изменений. Класс `FileWriter` же берет исходные байты и записывает в файл ДРУГИЕ байты. Вопрос - почему?)

Comment: см. апдейт ответа

Comment: мне сам механизм преобразования из байтов в `char` непонятен. ведь в компьютере нет понятия `char`. там информация хранится в битах (байтах, если угодно). А байт он и в Африке байт, а как его отображать - это уже вторичный вопрос.

Comment: Еще один апдейт

Comment: "как нам понять какие из себя представляют символы в этом наборе байтов?" смотрите важный момент - я пытаюсь записать разные символы, имеющие разные байты. Но записываются через `FileWriter` они почему-то одинаковым байтом, имеющим символ вопроса. Как такое возможно? P.S кстати, проверил все настройки IDE, везде стоит кодировка по умолчанию Win-1251

Comment: Прочтите так: `byte[] bytes = "abcdefghijz<аБ".getBytes("Win-1251);` - тогда все заработает, а иначе вы когда вы приводите `char` к байту через тупой каст - вы режете половину байта

Comment: Чего-то результат не поменялся
Ладно, пойду разбираться в настройках Eclipse